# Passing Date value from user defined table to a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Passing date value from system defined table to stored procedure called from vb.net results in an error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a DataTable to a DateTime

Code:

```
Dim ValueTable As New DataTable
ValueTable.Columns.Add("Value", GetType(Double))
ValueTable.Columns.Add("timestamp", GetType(DateTime))
ValueTable.Columns.Add("point", GetType(Integer))
ValueTable.Columns.Add("valueNumeric", GetType(Double))
```

User defined table is as

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ValueTable] AS TABLE
                               (
                                    OID int primary key,
                                    [Value] [float] NULL,
                                    [timestamp] [datetime]  NULL,
                                    [point] [int] NULL,
                                    [valueNumeric] [float] NULL
                               )
GO
```

And stored procedure as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Values]
      @tblValues AS ValueTable READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Value (Value, timestamp, Point, ValueNumeric)
        SELECT 
            Value, timestamp, point, valueNumeric 
        FROM 
            @tblValues
END
```

I need to insert multiple rows through stored procedure called from vb.net code.
When run as a `SqlCommand` from vb, I get this error:

> Database Error: Failed to convert parameter value from a DataTable to a DateTime.

Database is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the type you have created, you have 5 columns. Where as the data table which you have defined has only 4 columns defined. I think that's causing the issue. As well as you will need to change your stored procedure to include the OID column, since it's the primary key.